# FB.login dialog stucks on permission on IE9 

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>
       window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXX', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//localhost:63651/channel.htm', // Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth: true
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
<input type="button" value="login" id="login" onclick="return login();" />
<script>

    function login() {

        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, { scope: 'email,user_work_history,publish_stream' });



    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so my problem is , facebook dialog stucks on permission on IE9 see below [image: facebook error]

in chrome it works but with this error

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request from frame with URL http://localhost:63651/plans/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

i have used the same code as described fb documentation.

any help?
 i can provide more details if needed. i am out of all options. 
thanks

Comment: `http://localhost:63651/plans/` seems to me that you're trying to test it in localhost.. In my case FB connect only works on preprod or prod servers and I have to configure my FB Application with those domains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the channelURL file on the internet (no localhost url) and on the default http port (80). 
The problem might be that it doesn't recognize the different port for the connection, or that it want it published on the internet (not localhost)

```
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXX', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//your-website.com/channel.htm', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth: true
    });
```